# WPF Production Application not sending emails

Tags: c#, wpf, email

I have an application where it simply sends out an HTML email that has embedded Images. I used LinkedResource in order to add these images. When I send the email out from Visual Studio everything runs properly with no errors, however, when I send the emails from a Production environment it says it executed but with no errors or email.

I'm using Alternative views in order to complete this task.

```
SmtpClient clientDetails = new SmtpClient("Smtp.office365.com");
        clientDetails.Port = 587;
        clientDetails.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        clientDetails.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage sendEmail = new MailMessage();
LinkedResource getOffice = new LinkedResource(@"..\..\PocketProductivityClasses\HTMLImages\GetOffice.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

        getOffice.ContentId = "getOffice";

AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("SOMEHTMLHERE", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(getOffice);
sendEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        sendEmail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

        sendEmail.To.Add(sendToo);
        sendEmail.Subject = "Some Subject ";
        sendEmail.From = new MailAddress("Somewhere");

        //Send the email!
        clientDetails.Send(sendEmail);
```

Could this possibly be executing to quickly to gather all the details? I have about 9 embedded images

Comment: Everything you are doing in that code is done synchronously, so "executing too fast to gather all the details" isn't a problem.  From the client perspective, `Send` will either succeed or throw an exception.  If you are not getting an exception, then the SMTP server accepted the message from the client, but is failing to pass it to the recipient.  I would check the logs on the SMTP server for failures.

Comment: Are the destination addresses you are using to test and in production the same?  This could be a relay restriction or other anti-spam measure on the mail server.

Comment: Hey Bradley, Yes, they're all the same. A complete internal network that works while testing but not in production. It works when I modify it by taking the "Send.EmailAlternateViews.Add(avHtml)" portion out and just do a strict body as plain text. I just don't understand why sending it to the same recipient would not work in Production but work in visual studio.

Comment: Send.EmailAlternateViews.Add(avHtml) is failing then it could be avHtml is invalid. getOffice is added to avHtml. So are you sure the path of image is accessible in PROD.

Comment: Hey Mukul, I believe I'm adding the appropriate path. I have it separated in the folder as listed above. using the ..\..\ to change directories to it. Would this possibly be a problem with publishing in that case where the production environment doesn't see that folder or image. But even if it didn't see the image it should still send an email right?

Comment: I checked the logs to see if the email was actually sending by adding my personal account in there and checking the send logs but I'm not seeing any mail that was being sent. Its almost as if its completely skipping that section of the code.